# Translation of an expression "a dream commuter"

Tags: word-meaning

What the expression "a dream commuter" could possibly mean?

I met the expression in the title of the [article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/6385851.stm).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Honestly, I'd say it's not really a meaningful usage. Headlines can be like that. Probably the headline writer meant it to mean "Commuters whose commute is a dream", but I can only understand that by reading the whole article. (But I am an American --- maybe a British speaker will think it's more clear?)

Comment: BBC has a programme called "Dream Commuters". It is about people who live in France and go to the UK to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "dream *X*" in general is a very good example of *X*.

This comes from one of the definitions of *dream*,

> A person or thing perceived as wonderful or perfect.

[source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dream)

This is an example of a [noun modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), where one noun is used to add to the meaning of another noun.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So the expression is for commuters whose commute is usually wonderful?

Comment: It's not clear without context. I would think it's more likely to be used, for example, by a bus driver who really likes one of the riders on his bus.

Comment: Another possibility. A "commuter" is a kind of bicycle optimized for commuting. A "dream commuter" could be a very good example of that kind of bicycle.